# drupal commerce line item display

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce, commerce

I'm trying to learn how to use commerce module in drupal 7, and here I'm really confused.

In ( admin/commerce/products/types/product1/display/) I can manage display of product1 (for example) .It is clear that default display is used in nodes and teaser is used ofcourse in teaser mode, but "line item" doesn't make any sense. What is this display? where is this display used?

And also there is another one under store > config > line item types > product 1 > manage display (admin/commerce/config/line-items/product1/display). What's the difference between this and that one? What are these used for?

Answer (score 1):

A line item display is how the product is displayed in a cart / order. A line item can be a product, discount, shipping, etc

Comment: yes, but changing it's display doesn't make any sense, I actually change its view through views ui and changing these fields doesn't do anything